# Efficient storage and retrieval for heirarichal data in python

Tags: python

Consider the following class which contains a string, a float value, a numpy array and a dictionary.

The task is to store several gigabytes of this data to disk, and then later retrieve parts of the data selected by name, value, or an element of the dictionary.

Obviously one can do this by brute force, write the data to disk and then read all of it and search for the data that matches the search criteria.  But for gigabytes of data, that takes a prohibitively long time.

Is there a simple way to do this more efficiently in python?  And if so, can you please provide a simple example using this class?  Thank you.

```
class DATA:

    def __init__( self, name, float_value, list_of_values, dict_of_values ):

       self.name = name

       self.value = float_value

       self.vector = np.array( list_of_values )

       self.dictionary = dict_of_values
```

Comment: What's the datatypes in the dictionary? String keys? What's the type(s) of the values?  And is the `name` the unique key of the object, or will you assign unique keys if needed?  I assume list_of_values is numerical, since you use numpy (it could technically be any python object, which you'd need to tell us :).

Comment: You basically try to reinvent databases. You better use them, as they're much more mature products than you'll ever write

Comment: In what way is the data hierarchical? Is it about the name, or something else?

Comment: @creanion the name is a string, the next two are floats, and the dictionary contains string keys and float values.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov  Okay, which one is right for this?   I checked and didn't see one that does this on first perusual.

Comment: @creanion, the dictionary can make it heirachical

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov   P/S  I hope that indeed there is something like a database for this.  Note that I asked if there is a simple way to do it.  I want to avoid having to write my own indexing system, for example.

Comment: Is the `several gigabytes of ... data` a single instance of the class or many-many instances of the class. I like the database suggestion, you just need to figure out how to design the tables. And maybe add a hardware component, maybe an SSD RAID.

Comment: @wwii  It is a list of several thousand instances of the class.  I need to retrieve instances selected by the of one of the elements.  I have listed the example with one stored value, but in fact there are several.  For example, if elements are time and voltage, I made want all instances with a particular value of voltage, or all elements with a particular value of time.